# CCS PIC16F628A Out of ROM, A segment or the program is too large

Tags: c, compiler-errors, microcontroller, rom

I'm not sure if this question should go to electronics or not, but since it's about programming, I asked it here.

I am making a digital clock using LEDs powered by a shift register instead of a 7 segment display. Anyway, when compiling the code using [CCS](http://www.ccsinfo.com), I get the following error:

```
***Error 71 "test.c" Line 195(0,1) Out of ROM, A segment or the program is too large  num
Seg 00004-007FF, 07DC left, need 07EA
Seg 00000-00003, 0000 left, need 07EA
```

and here is my code so far:

```
#include <16f628a.h>
#use delay (crystal=32768)

//to display a number on the LEDs using the 74164 shift register accordingly
void num(int rnum, char out, char clk) {
   
//start clear shift register   
   output_high(clk);
   output_low(clk);
   output_high(clk);
   output_low(clk);
   output_high(clk);
   output_low(clk);
   output_high(clk);
   output_low(clk);
   output_high(clk);
   output_low(clk);
   output_high(clk);
   output_low(clk);
   output_high(clk);
   output_low(clk);
   output_high(clk);
   output_low(clk);
//end clear shift register
   
   switch(rnum) {
      case 0:
         output_high(out);
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
         output_low(out);
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
         output_high(out);
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
         output_low(out);
         
         break;
      case 1:
         output_low(out);
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
         output_high(out);
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
         output_low(out);
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
         output_high(out);
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
         output_low(out);
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
         break;
      case 2:
         output_high(out);//7
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
         output_low(out);//6
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
         output_high(out);//5
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
         output_high(clk);//4
         output_low(clk);
         output_high(clk);//3
         output_low(clk);
         output_low(out);//2
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
         output_high(out);
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
         output_low(out);
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
      break;
      case 3:
         output_high(out);//7
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
         output_high(clk);//6
         output_low(clk);
         output_high(clk);//5
         output_low(clk);
         output_low(out);//4
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
         output_high(out);//3
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
         output_low(out);//2
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
         output_high(out);//1
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
         output_low(out);
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
      break;
      case 4:
         output_high(out);//7
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
         output_high(out);//6
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
         output_low(out);//5
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
         output_low(out);//4
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
         output_high(out);//3
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
         output_high(out);//2
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
         output_low(out);//1
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
      break;
      case 5:
         output_low(out);//7
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
         output_high(out);//6
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
         output_high(out);//5
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
         output_low(out);//4
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
         output_high(out);//3
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
         output_high(out);//2
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
         output_high(out);//1
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
         output_low(out);//reset
         output_high(clk);
         output_low(clk);
      break;
   }
}

//==============================


void main() {
   while(true) {
      num(0, pin_a1, pin_a0);
      delay_ms(2000);
      num(1, pin_a1, pin_a0);
      delay_ms(2000);
      num(2, pin_a1, pin_a0);
      delay_ms(2000);
      num(3, pin_a1, pin_a0);
      delay_ms(2000);
      num(4, pin_a1, pin_a0);
      delay_ms(2000);
      num(5, pin_a1, pin_a0);
      delay_ms(2000);
   }
}
```

Can somebody please help me with this problem regarding that I'm a newbie to this subject?

Answer (score 0):

Your pragma/complier/linker settings seem to indicate you are building for an XXk size ROM/EEPROM but your program needs a device > XXk size.  Look for config and/or header file settings that set the size of the target device.

Comment: As I said before, I'm new to this subject, therefore I barely understand what you said. However, if it has anything to do with changing settings of the header file, I don't think that would work because it is written based on the hardware (in this case the PIC16F628A) which has static (cannot be changed) settings.

Comment: Okay. That rules out the header file.  That device has 128 bytes of EEPROM data memory and 3.5 KB of program memory.  Could your program simply been too large for the device?

Comment: I read things that mentioned hardware pages and a #separate command, however, I didn't really understand it: http://www.ccsinfo.com/faq.php?page=out_of_rom

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you would have thought of the function with this code, but the error is probably due exactly as it is stated (Out of ROM, A segment or the program is too large).

When you use 'output_high', the program memory is used, which means that all these 'output_high() and output_low()' take up far too much space.
PIC12F628 has only 2048 word program memory.

Try writing to the whole port directly with 'output_x ()', where you enter in hexadecimal the values of the whole port.

For example, you will write to

1. output_high(PIN_A0)
2. output_low(PIN_A1)
3. output_low(PIN_A2)
4. output_low(PIN_A3)
5. output_low(PIN_A4)
6. output_low(PIN_A5)
7. output_high(PIN_A6)
8. output_high(PIN_A7)

It's then better to write 'output_a(0xC1).
It's exactly the same thing that happens, but you use less program memory.

**The pins separate have**

1. PIN_A0 (0x01) //   1
2. PIN_A1 (0x02) //   2
3. PIN_A2 (0x04) //   4
4. PIN_A3 (0x08) //   8
5. PIN_A4 (0x10) //  16
6. PIN_A5 (0x20) //  32
7. PIN_A6 (0x40) //  64
8. PIN_A7 (0x80) // 128

But wwhen you merge them, you must learn how to adding hex.

See all of the pins of the gates as binary numbers

```
 **Hex: Dec   Bin:**
```

1. 0    0    0000 0000
2. 1    1    0000 0001
3. 2    2    0000 0010
4. 3    3    0000 0011
5. 4    4    0000 0100
6. 5    5    0000 0101
7. 6    6    0000 0110
8. 7    7    0000 0111
9. 8    8    0000 1000
10. 9    9    0000 1001
11. A    10   0000 1010
12. B    11   0000 1011
13. C    12   0000 1100
14. D    13   0000 1101
15. E    14   0000 1110
16. F    15   0000 1111

**Example 1.**

1. output_high(PIN_A0)
2. output_high(PIN_A1)
3. output_high(PIN_A2)
4. output_low(PIN_A3)
5. output_low(PIN_A4)
6. output_low(PIN_A5)
7. output_low(PIN_A6)
8. output_low(PIN_A7)

It's better to write 'output_a(0x07).

**Example 2.**

1. output_high(PIN_A0)
2. output_low(PIN_A1)
3. output_low(PIN_A2)
4. output_high(PIN_A3)
5. output_low(PIN_A4)
6. output_low(PIN_A5)
7. output_low(PIN_A6)
8. output_high(PIN_A7)

Add PIN_A7 with PIN_A3 and PIN_A0: 128+8+1=137 hex(0x89) bin(10001001).

I think this should be enough for you to know how to write your programs to save on program memory.

Best Regards
// Tommy Hjertezén